# Trying to pass an IEntity to a list constructor and having trouble

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, ienumerable

I have a customer object that has a list of sales orders. I am trying to create a partial view on my webpage that lets me use radio buttons to click through and see the lists per customer. The issue is that in the customer controller, I need to pass the customer IEntity (via an id) to the constructor.

I tried looking this up but I am new to all this and I don't think I am using the right words or maybe I just don't understand well enough yet to find the answer in other peoples code.

Customer Object (and constructor obviously)

```
public class Customer : IEntity 
{
    [Key]
    public int CustomerId { get; set; }
    public int Id => CustomerId;
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Customer")]
    public virtual string Name => $"{FirstName} {LastName}";
    [Display(Name = "Address")]
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "City")]
    public string City { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "State")]
    public string State { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Zipcode")]
    public string Zipcode { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Display(Name = "Phone Number (USA)")]
    public string UsaPhone { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalSales => SalesOrders.Sum(so => so.OrderTotal);
    public List<SalesOrder> SalesOrders { get; private set; }
    public Customer()
    {
        SalesOrders = new List<SalesOrder>();
    }

}
```

Code from the Customer Controller where I am getting the error

```
public ActionResult _customersSalesOrders(int id)
    {
        var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
        var salesOrderList = new List<SalesOrder>(customer);
        return PartialView(salesOrderList);
    }
```

The result is error CS1503 "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'ITP245.Models.Customer' to 'int'

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new `List<SalesOrder>`, which means you can only place into it objects that are of type `SalesOrder`. Your `Customer` class does not inherit from `SalesOrder` & cannot be placed into the list.

Maybe you mean to place the customer's sales orders into the list?

If so, your code might look something like this:

```
public ActionResult _customersSalesOrders(int id)
{
    var customer = db.Customers.Find(id);
    var salesOrderList = customer.SalesOrders;
    return PartialView(salesOrderList);
}
```

Comment: I think this is the answer to my question, unfortunately I seem to have missed something in my code that will let the actual partial view render so I need to figure that out before I can confirm. Thank you for your help!